# Ceiling lamp (LED) with dimmer function

Tags: lighting, light

I am looking for a LED ceiling lamp that should have at least the following characteristics:

- warm white light
- luminous flux at least 2500lm
- flux gradually dimmable via rotary dimmer switch in the wall (no remote control), dimmer and lamp can be separate products

After some research I could not find such a model so far. Either the dimming works only via remote control, or the lamp is not bright enough or the dimmer switch is only adjustable in steps (usually it is a 3 way switch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stuck in "appliance mode". You really need to separate out into:

- Light Fixture

plus

- Switch

In the old days it was simple. A light fixture was a gadget that held some sort of bulb(s) - regular incandescent, candelabra incandescent, fluorescent tube. And later some additional types - various halogen types, etc.

If you wanted *anything* fancier than on/off it had to be done at the same switch that handled on/off. Dimmer, timer, motion sensor, etc.

Now there are "smart fixtures" and "smart bulbs". An example of a smart fixture (to some degree) is a ceiling fan/light with a wireless remote control. The wireless remote can turn the light on/off and dim it, and it can turn the fan on/off and adjust the speed. Sounds great, right? Until you lose the remote. Or someone turns off the switch on the other side of the room (3-way switches are quite common for a light fixture in a large room...that gets replaced with a fan/light) that you had either never known what it was (and neither does the person who turned it off, because the fan and light were off at the time) or that you stuck a piece of tape on it "don't touch this" (I grew up in a house with a timer on a 3-way switch like that). Etc.

So "smart fixtures" are not always so smart.

"Smart bulbs"? Even worse. Often designed to be controlled via WiFi. What happens when the router is replaced or the WiFi Key is changed? What about guests who have no clue how to get it to work? Etc.

The solution is simple:

- Light Fixture

Pick a fixture which has the light qualities you want (warm white, 2500 lm, dimmable) or that takes bulbs and get bulbs that match the light qualities you want. That should be trivially easy to find.

- Switch

Get a switch that has the capabilities you want. That would include an LED-compatible dimmer. It may include other functions such as timer or WiFi control or motion sensor. But the bottom line is that it is a *switch*. So you can press it or toggle it to get the light to turn on and off.

Then if you want more light you replace the fixture. If you want more other features you replace the switch. But they are two separate things. Not a package deal.

Comment: This is not an answer. Of course lamp and switch are different devices. I could not find a light with properties warm white, >=2500 lm, gradually dimmable.

Comment: Trivially easy. For example, any fixture that can take medium Edison base bulbs and can take 2 or 3 smaller dimmable warm white bulbs - e.g., here is a 1600 lumen dimmable 3000K - any 2-bulb fixture that can take standard bulbs + any LED-compatible dimmer switch. Done. Harder (not impossible) to find a fixture with integrated LEDs that match the specs. Need to be flexible with "how" as long as you get the results (2500+ lm, 3000K, dimmable) you actually want.

Comment: I am not an electrician. I need a ready solution that can be bought somewhere.

Comment: And I'm telling you the solution is to pick *either* a fixture with integrated dimmable LEDs matching your specs or which has standard Edison bases (a.k.a. "regular old light bulb") and a matching number of warm white, appropriate lumens (2500+ divided by number of bulbs) dimmable LED bulbs + a standard rotary LED compatible dimmer (which is an inexpensive readily available item). This is not hard to do. I'd shop it for you except (a) that's off-topic here and (b) actual fixture *style* is very subjective so that won't help anyway. But go to any lighting store or Home Depot (or local

Comment: equivalent) and this should be truly easy to find. What you won't easily find is a package of "dimmable 2500+lm fixture and rotary dimmer". They're not a package. It is 2 (fixture + dimmer switch) or 3 (fixture + bulbs + dimmer switch) separate things that work together.

Comment: You will then need either an electrician or some basic electrical skills (which *are* learnable for a determined DIY) to install.

Comment: Please show me a lamp and a suitable dimmer.

Comment: 5-light fixture https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Helena-21-in-5-Light-Brushed-Nickel-Hanging-Chandelier-with-Frosted-Glass-Shades-for-Dining-Room-21095-000/313572641 + warm white bulbs https://www.homedepot.com/p/Philips-60-Watt-Equivalent-A19-Ultra-Definition-Dimmable-E26-LED-Light-Bulb-Soft-White-with-Warm-Glow-2700K-4-Pack-576116/321121512 (800 lb x 5 = 4,000 > 2,500) + rotary dimmer https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Trimatron-600-Watt-Single-Pole-Universal-Rotary-Dimmer-White-Light-Almond-R00-RNL06-0TW/301370402

Comment: Always "Access denied."

Comment: Huh? Either you have a wacky firewall of some sort, or you are outside the US and homedepot.com isn't allowing access for some reason. Don't know. But bottom line is: Find a fixture that matches (except for dimmer, that's separate) or that takes bulbs + bulbs that match your specs, + an LED-compatible rotary dimmer. All readily available in US/Canada, and should be, in one form or another, around the world.

Comment: How about Europe?

Comment: Europe is a big place. I suspect that the stores/products in England vs. France vs. Spain vs. Germany will vary quite a bit. But the basics are the same - look for a fixture that is dimmable or that takes regular bulbs + bulbs that are dimmable. Then look for a rotary dimmer. Done. This is **not** a shopping site. This is a site of "how to do stuff" - I told you *how* - get the pieces separately not as a package. The shopping is up to you.

Comment: But such a question is also not capable by Google.

Comment: Europe is a big place. Well, so is the US - but in the US I know I can pick Home Depot or Lowes and cover the vast majority of the country. So you need to start with "what are the big retailers of lighting and electrical parts in my country/region" and then either walk into one of those stores *or* find that store's web site on Google and shop online.

Comment: @ Author,  How about manassehkatz get on a plane and comes over to your house and does everything for you.